# More concise way to round 0.5 and below to zero?

Tags: sql-server, rounding

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(0.51 AS FLOAT), 0) AS FiveOne
     , ROUND(CAST(0.5 AS FLOAT), 0) AS Five
     , ROUND(CAST(0.4999999 AS FLOAT), 0) AS FourNine

FiveOne                Five                   FourNine
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                      1                      0
```

How can I make the 0.5 and 0.49999 round to zero (down to the nearest whole number) but the 0.51 round to 1?
I figure I can do the following, but is there a more concise way?

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(0.51 AS FLOAT), 0) AS FiveOne
     , CASE WHEN CAST(0.5 AS FLOAT) <= CAST(0.5 AS FLOAT)
            THEN FLOOR(CAST(0.5 AS FLOAT))
            ELSE ROUND(CAST(0.5 AS FLOAT), 0)
       END AS Five
     , ROUND(CAST(0.4999999 AS FLOAT), 0) AS FourNine

FiveOne                Five                   FourNine
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                      0                      0
```

Comment: Banker's rounding ?

Comment: Sure if that's the name for it, I'm just splitting one quantity into two and don't want an additional one to appear if I do a 50/50 split on an odd number.

Comment: When custom rounding, mod (`%`) should be your operator to go.

Comment: This isn't Banker's Rounding.

Comment: yes. you are right @nicomp

Comment: Be careful using floats here. You seem to be concerned with accurate (albeit rounded) results. In that case you should use an exact datatype like numeric instead of an approximate like float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this

```
select  amt, ceiling(amt - 0.5)
from
(
    select  amt = 0.51  union all
    select  0.5     union all
    select  0.4999999   
) a
```

RESULT :

```
0.5100000   1
0.5000000   0
0.4999999   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Round the number normally, but subtract `.5` if its remainder when dividing by `1` is `.5`:

```
select
  round(case when v % 1 = .5 then v - .5 else v end, 0)
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support mod in the way you proposed.

Comment: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b3c564bc1723e12c0b5673f87c73deb) Shouldn't it be `-0.5` instead of `+0.5`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use third parameter of [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) combined with `CASE`:

> ROUND ( numeric_expression , length **[ ,function ]** )
>
> When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. **When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.**

```
DECLARE @v DECIMAL(18,8) = 0.5;
SELECT ROUND(@v, 0, CASE WHEN @v %0.5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74378bb61fc409fa1bc224626ff17f0b)**